# Does real analytic imply locally contractible?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analytic-structures

The statement is true for complex analytic spaces. I am not sure who proved this result.

I ask the same question in the real case.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I'm not sure if you are talking about manifolds with analytic structures, spaces of such manifolds or structures, functions spaces of (some or all) analytic functions or something else.

Comment: Yes, because every real analytic set is triangulable.   Check the paper *Geometric categories and o-minimal structures* by Chris Miller and  Lou van der Dries, Duke Math J 84(1996).

Comment: Joonas, I am asking whether the zero locus of finitely many real analytic functions, is locally contractible as a topological space.

Comment: Liviu, can you point me to a more specific statement in the paper? Thanks!